# How can I activate an application in AppleScript without switching desktops?

Tags: macos, applescript, spaces

I'm trying to write an AppleScript that will open a new Safari window on my current desktop space. That's easy enough. The catch is that I've already got a Safari window running on another space, and I don't want to switch to that space, or have the new window show up on that space.

Is there a way to tell AppleScript to open the new window on the current space regardless of which spaces Safari might be active on?

I've got two options for the basic AppleScript. The first switches to the space that Safari is active on, and then opens the new window;

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        click menu item "New Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

The second just opens a new window on Safari's current space, without switching desktops.

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document 
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put the activate command after the command for opening a new window?

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to work sometimes, but other times (most of the time) it creates two new Safari windows. One on the current desktop, and one on another desktop, which it switches to. I can't figure out why this script would create two new documents. (I am activating the script with Alfred, which may have something to do with it.)